# Return multiple result sets in MYSQL using stored procedure in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, laravel-5

I'm preforming a query six times to return me multiple result sets. The query is same for all call but the params only vary. It is as follows:

```
public function getGroupedInfo($id, $type, $zip,  $field) {

    return DB::table('data')
             ->select(DB::raw("{$field} as obj, COUNT(*) as count"))
             ->where('report_id', $id)
             ->where('book_section', $type)
             ->where('zip_code', $zip)
             ->groupBy("{$field}")
             ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')->get();

}
```

I'm calling the function as follows:

```
public function stats(Request $request){
    $schools['Elementary Schools'] = $this->getGroupedInfo($id, $listing_type, $zip_code, 'elementary_school');
    $schools['Middle Schools'] = $this->getGroupedInfo($id, $listing_type, $zip_code, 'middle_school');
    $schools['High Schools'] = $this->getGroupedInfo($id, $listing_type, $zip_code, 'high_school');
    $others['lot_sqft'] = $this->getGroupedInfo($id, $listing_type, $zip_code, 'lot_sqft');
}
```

I was planning on adding them to a single stored procedure, but I'm not sure how to write these in a single stored procedure and then work with the results on Laravel end.

Can you please help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are always querying the count of the same four fields, you can write down a stored procedure with four `SELECT` statements concatenated using `UNION`, as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCounts
(
    IN ReportId INT,
    IN ListingType VARCHAR(100),
    IN ZipCode INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'elementary_school' AS type, elementary_school AS obj, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM data
    WHERE report_id = @ReportId AND book_section = @ListingType AND zip_code = @ZipCode
    GROUP BY elementary_school
    ORDER BY count DESC

    UNION

    SELECT 'middle_school' AS type, middle_school AS obj, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM data
    WHERE report_id = @ReportId AND book_section = @ListingType AND zip_code = @ZipCode
    GROUP BY middle_school
    ORDER BY count DESC

    UNION

    SELECT 'high_school' AS type, high_school AS obj, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM data
    WHERE report_id = @ReportId AND book_section = @ListingType AND zip_code = @ZipCode
    GROUP BY high_school
    ORDER BY count DESC

    UNION

    SELECT 'lot_sqft' AS type, lot_sqft AS obj, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM data
    WHERE report_id = @ReportId AND book_section = @ListingType AND zip_code = @ZipCode
    GROUP BY lot_sqft
    ORDER BY count DESC
END;
```

Then, you can call it as follows:

```
DB::select('EXEC GetCounts(?,?,?)', array($id, $listing_type, $zip_code));
```

Comment: awesome man!, works like a charm. Could you explain the UNION in this scenario, how's that working?

Comment: It just concatenates the result of every select into a single result. Read this link for more information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: nice... That makes things a lot more understandable. Thanks Tom.

Comment: Note the 'union' command will remove duplicate rows. The 'union all' does not.